# Is there a way to execute a void only once at a certain time?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've got an activity with a recyclerview, and I want that recyclerview to show different listItems every time. That works, but I want this to run only once(at a certain hour eg. 00:00h) and not to run again every time that I get into the activity all the void that randomly decides which item to show on the recyclerview.

Here's the code:

```
public class Comida2 extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador2.OnRecipeListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    List<Entidad2> listItems;
    Adaptador2 adaptor;
    private Entidad2 entidad1,entidad2,entidad3;
    Button cambiarmenu;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

        cambiarmenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_cambiarmenu);

        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        entidad1 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Solomillo a la plancha", " 10 min.", 4, 20);
        entidad2 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Entrecot", " 15 min.", 2, 50);
        entidad3 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.tomate, "Hamburguesa", " 2 min.", 5, 100);


        listItems.add(entidad1);
        listItems.add(entidad2);
        listItems.add(entidad3);

        adaptor = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(adaptor);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public void OnRecipe(int priority) {

        if (priority == 20) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Solomillo.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 50) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Entrecot.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 100) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Hamburguesa.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    public void pickEntidad(){
        final int random = new Random().nextInt(101);

        int priority1 = entidad1.getPriority();
        int priority2 = entidad2.getPriority();
        int priority3 = entidad3.getPriority();


        listItems.clear();
        if(random < priority1){

            listItems.add(entidad1);

        }else if(random < priority2){

            listItems.add(entidad2);

        }else if (random <= priority3){

            listItems.add(entidad3);

        }
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I've looked at some other posts but the problem is that I want all that process to run one time when I first get into the app and then I'd shut down the app. After that, get in the app and still not run the void. But it should run at a certain hour, 00:00h would be ok as an example.

In addition, I'd like to add a button on a **different** activity which can run the void in **this** activity and therefore change what is randomly shown on the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

Use  WorkManager and schedule a job to run at 0:00h every night.  Have it pick the items to show and write them to a file.  Then when your activity runs, have it read that file and display those items.

For the button in the activity, have it delete the file.  Code the RecyclerView activity to generate the file itself if there is none to begin with (showing a loading screen if necessary at the beginning).

Comment: I've been reading on Android developers because I've never used WorkManager, and I have two questions: 1st: How to set a certain hour eg. 0:00h      2nd: How do I make it pick the items, should I move the PickEntidad and OnRecipe methods to the Worker class? @Gabe Sechan

Comment: What do you mean by writing them to a file?(java file?) Please help with that

Comment: A file.  A data file.  In whatever format you find easiest.